Down stream oxygen sensor wiring code
I had my catalytic converter stolen on my 2013 Toyota Tacoma and they cut the oxygen sensor wires so I bought one from e bay and the down stream sensor also my problem is I don't know how to match the one i bought is supposed to be a denso with a purple,grey,black,and white wires so the pig tail left on my truck colors are the oem blue,white,black and black I need to connect them properly but don't know how, can some one please help me with this issue thank you

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

From a quick search, it seems your part may be a repackaged Delphi sensor, which has the following color coding:

Signal: Black
Ground: Grey
Heater: Purple + White

Match those to OEM colors, which are

Signal: White
Ground: Light Blue with White
Heater: Black + Black or
Black + Green

The positions of the heater wires don't matter (e.g. they can be swapped).
Sources:

https://images.app.goo.gl/b3WP1oDLMt2W8Gnq7
https://images.app.goo.gl/74nGzG6qoJAaR4kc9

